# Folder for Release build does not get created when publishing .NET Core

Tags: bash, .net-core, publish

Hello i am using a bash script to get the `publish` folder from on source and to put it in the folder of another appliation.

The problem is that while i use `dotnet publish` the `publish` folder gets created only for the `Debug` build.
Even with my project  on `Release` build  set the `dotnet` command generates for the `Debug`.What am i doing wrong?

**Bash Script**

```
releasepath="D:\Work\redius\core\redius\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish" 
destpath="D:\dotpeek"
rediuspath="D:\Work\redius"
curDir="$(pwd)\out.txt"

if  [ ! -f curDir ]; 
then  
touch  $curDir
fi

echo $releasepath
rm -rf  $destpath
mkdir $destpath
(cd $rediuspath &&  dotnet publish | $curDir && echo "done publishing")
echo "Copying from : ${releasepath} to ${destpath}"
cp -rf  releasepath destpath
cd
```

I need the folder present for the first line of the script.I have tried with `publish` from `vstudio` but it creates a `nupkg` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build the project with `dotnet build -c Release`. Then it will be able to create dll in Release mode.

Comment: But isn't the publishing supposed to do the build too ? A build is like a publish having the dependencies locally.And i have build the project from within visual studio.

Comment: This worked for me. I was not getting the build from Release after doing publish. Explicit build in release mode solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

`dotnet publish` first builds the project and then publishes it. By default the build configuration `Debug` is used.

If you want to build your project with the build configuration `Release` you have to specify the `-c` flag.

```
dotnet publish -c Release
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21

If you need to specify additional build flags you can first build the project and then publish it.

```
dotnet build -c Release
dotnet publish --no-build
```